# GetItemAt returning null value instead of ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two ComboBox with same items.
I am trying to get the ComboBoxItem of a ComboBox by Index but NULL value is being returned.
My code is:

```
var index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
ComboBoxItem item = comboBox2.Items.GetItemAt(index) as ComboBoxItem; // item is null here

//item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
//also tried above line but same result(null)
```

And XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ExistingModuleGroups}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModuleGroup}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Name="comboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding ExistingModuleGroups}">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
     {
          if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
          {
                var index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
                ComboBoxItem item = comboBox2.Items.GetItemAt(index) as ComboBoxItem; // item is null here
                 //item.IsEnabled = false;
          }

     }
}
```

Any idea...

Comment: you are selecting index from combobox"1" and trying to get an item at that index from combobox"2" - is this by design?

Comment: Yes @Krishna. Its by design.

Comment: and you checked that the index is less than count of combobox2.Items.counts?

Comment: Everything I have checked. All are ok. Both ComboBoxes have same number, type and order of items. I want to disable the item in ComboBox2 if it's already selected in ComboBox1

Answer (score 2):

The `ItemsControl.Items` property stores the actual data, not the generated ComboBoxItems (unless you've manually added objects of type ComboBoxItem to the Items collection).

You were close with that second piece of code you've commented, but you were looking for an item from the first combo in the second combo. Since you are probably not using the same instances for both combos, that won't work.

The correct thing would probably be this. Similar to what you've already tried, but with some key differences:

```
var index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;  // Get the index from the first combo
var item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.ItemContainerGenerator
               .ContainerFromIndex(index);  // And get the ComboBoxItem from that index
                                            // in the second combo
```

Comment: What's "not working"? If your comboBox2 has at least as many items as comboBox1, that code has to return you an item. What error are you getting? index is not greater than zero? Casting fails? It doesn't return the item you expect?

Comment: comboBox2.Items.Count gives 8. Even comboBox2.Items.GetItemAt(3) is also giving null. No exception.

Comment: I'm not using `GetItemAt`... I'm using `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex()`. If there are 8 items in comboBox2, and you call `comboBox2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(3)`, I can assure you that it won't return null.

Comment: Technically, it should be as "easy" as it sounds... Doesn't simply `item.IsEnabled = false` work?

Comment: That's a different question, though. Maybe you should open a new post with that one.